# singleton ejb mixing concurrency issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, singleton, ejb

I read few articles on the Internet about `@Singleton` and how it has by `default` the container managed concurrency however I cant figure out following issue:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MySBean {

    @Lock(WRITE)
    private void load() {
    ...
    }

    @Lock(READ)
    public Data getData(String match, ...) {
        ...
        load();  // does singleton syncs all calls from getData() to load()?
        ...
    }
}
```

All those simple articles online described how once a client calls a method annotationed with `READ` for instance many `@Stateless` beans inject `@Singleton` it allows multple access to that method at the same time because of `READ`. Does a client access a method annotationed with `WRITE` the `@Singleton` instance forces other `threads/stateless beans` to wait. But what happens when you mix them?

What happens when there are two or more calls at same time to `getData` method?

Answer (score 0):

- As long as `getData` is entered by any thread, `load` is blocked for other threads, but `getData` is allowed.
- As long as `load` is entered by one thread, both `load` and `getData` are blocked for other threads.

See: [Managing Concurrent Access in a Singleton Session Bean](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html)

Comment: your answer is not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I answered to: "What happens when there are two or more calls at same time to getData method?" what is yet open? Is blocked means, the thread waits for a certain time, until the blocking is removed or the Timeout occurs. The timeout happens after 5 seconds, then the thread will get an Exception.

Comment: to sum up - getData() method may be called by different threads as long one of them is NOT the first to enter load() method. Once that happens, nobody can call geData() anymore means thread are waiting and those threads who did access getData but werent first are also waiting for load() to finish, right?

Comment: if that includes, that: load must wait as long as any other thread has entered getData(), then yes. Example: A is in getData(), B is in getData() and tries load .. B must wait until A has left getData(). If A meanwhile tries to enter load .. deadlock because of both waiting for each other to leave getData(). Which should either be detected or both wait until the first of them encountered a timeout.

Comment: B and A are both inside getData and B is the first who enters load() method. That would mean to me that B runs normally and A waits for B to finish load() the it enters load() for iteself and proceeds with the rest of getData() method. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: no B must not enter load() as long as A has not left getData(). Otherwise it would not make sense to let anybody wait at getData as long as another thread is working in load()

Comment: I dont get you sorry maybe its because of my english. Lets keep it simple. There are two threads A and B.. both may enter getData() since its marked as @Read annotation. However only one of them will enter load() first from getData().. Lets say B enters load() from getData(). what happens with A? it must enter load too since its also inside getData() just B was faster, no?

Comment: Sorry, I can only repeat the same. If the call to load() happens during getData() then this call will will **blocked** until all **other** threads have **left** getData(). if that is not possible because of another thread trying to enter load() inside getData() -- **Deadlock** -- which will be solved by exception thrown by the container either immediately or after the timeout.